# Perl appending (s)printf output to string

Tags: perl

I'm parsing some data and organizing it, and now I need to capture it inside a variable.

I've never used printf or sprintf before this.

I'm using printf in a manner like this to organize the data:

```
printf("%-30s %18s %18s\n", "$a", "$b", "$c\n");
```

Now I have a variable that's storing a string, and I want to append the organized data to the variable $result.

I tried something like

```
$result.printf("%-30s %18s %18s\n", "$a", "$b", "$c\n");
```

and it doesn't work. I tried sprintf too.

Any ideas?

Thanks, S

Comment: I think I speak for everyone here when I say "doesn't work" is the third least helpful diagnostic message of all time. Tell us what you expected to happen and tell us what actually happened.

Comment: @mob I am curious: What are the top two least helpful?

Comment: Could people please stop wrapping lone variables with quotes? Would you do it in C or Python? Why do you do it in Perl? Let's call it "Useless use of variable interpolation." Also, you have \n both in your format string and the last argument to printf. Did you really want two linefeeds in your output?

Comment: Seems [I am not the first to use that phrase](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=906748)

Comment: @runrig you would do it in the shell, which is more perl-like than python.

Comment: @jordanm - Ah, that makes sense, so that's where people get it from...well, they should still stop it (in Perl) :-)

Comment: yeah, it makes a completely needless copy of a var.

Answer (score 12):

`printf` outputs the constructed string to the specified handle (or the current default if omitted) and returns a boolean which indicates whether an IO error occurred or not. Not useful. `sprintf` returns the constructed string, so you want this.

To concatenate two strings (append one to another), one uses the `.` operator (or `join`)

```
$result . sprintf(...)
```

But you said this doesn't work. Presumably, it's because you also want to store the produced string in `$result`, which you can do using

```
$result = $result . sprintf(...);
```

or the shorter

```
$result .= sprintf(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you mean by "tried sprintf too", because there's no reason it would not work if you do it right. Although that syntax you showed does not look much like perl, more like python or ruby?

```
my $foo = sprintf("%-30s %18s %18s\n", "$a", "$b", "$c\n");
$result .= $foo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes, sorry for the lack of specificity in "it doesn't work".  I should have been more specific.  It worked, or I was able to save the sprintf formatting inside a variable for appending to a .txt file, by appending variable to variable like you showed vs. appending the sprintf statement to a variable like I was trying to do.

Comment: @user1610717 `$foo` is just a transition variable, you could just as easily have appended `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks very much...appending the variables together worked fine as TLP suggested.